# Shorten an if statement whose statement are reversed

Tags: python, algorithm, if-statement, code-readability

I have the following situation:

```
string = "abc"
if (string[1] == "b" and string[2] == "c") or (string[1] == "c" and string[2] == "b"):
    print("ERROR")
```

Is there a solution to shorten this in a pythonic way?
I see that `(string[1] == "b" and string[2] == "c")` is the reverse statement of `(string[1] == "c" and string[2] == "b")`. Maybe I can use that?

Comment: `string[1] == "b" and string[2] == "c"` isn't the reverse statement of `string[1] == "c" and string[2] == "b"`. This is `!(string[1] == "b" and string[2] == "c")` or `string[1] != "b" OR string[2] != "c"`

Comment: Are the indices important, or do you actually want to check if the substr "bc" or "cb" exists inside `string` ?

Comment: @Cid Sorry, I mean only "b" and "c" are swapped

Comment: @magnus question is important concerning your problem

Comment: @magnus I want to check if the substring "bc" or "cb" exists inside the string. But they have to be the second an third letter

Comment: @Cid I don't understand your comment? I'm not the OP.

Comment: @magnus I know, I'm telling OP that your question is relevant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Is there a solution to shorten this in a pythonic way?*

Yes, here it is:

```
string = "abc"
if (string[1:3] == "bc") or (string[1:3] == "cb"):
    print("ERROR")
```

---

If eagering for a more short way - `if string[1:3] in ('bc', 'cb'):`

Comment: Might add that if the pattern is arbitrary and stored in a variable named, say `pattern="bc"`, it may be reversed by `pattern[::-1]` to obtain "cb"